# Making a copy of a disk without installing software

Tags: windows-xp, backup

What would be the easiest way to make an image copy of an internal HDD to an external USB one (HDD) without any installing of additional software? Image copy, as in, I wish to have a complete copy which I can boot it on another computer.

Comment: If you don't want to install any software we need to know your OS is to know what utilities are already available to you. And while you're intention is to not install software, would booting from a live CD be acceptable?

Comment: @DMA57361 - So sorry. I always seem to forget that part. I've modified the tags. As for the live CD booting, yes, it would be acceptable. Or any other scheme. The only constaints are that I cannot write to the internal disc, and wish to back it to the usb disc.

Answer (score 2):

The Live CD [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) comes with the tool partimage. It allows you to create an image of a disk to another one and restore it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/). It makes use of partimage, dd and/or partclone and it can be used to duplicate partitions, as you require.

Also, since it is a Live CD (or USB) this can be done without writing anything to the source partition.